# use json as powershell config file

Tags: json, powershell

```
$Config = (Get-Content -Raw -Path $configFile)| ConvertFrom-Json -Verbose
```

Results in:

```
@{val1=value1; val2=value2}
```

For input file:
{
    "val1": "value1",
    "val2": "value2"
}

Where am I going wrong here, it looks like I get a string back.

Answer (score -1):

Turns out I was overwriting my $Config file variable from higher up in the script.  Essentially it looks like once a variable has a type the runtime tries to keep it.  So it was a string at one point, it stays a string.